# Summing two Poisson distributions with SymPy

Tags: sympy

I'm new to SymPy and I'm trying to use it to sum two Poisson distributions

Here's what I have so far (using jupyter notebook)

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import *
init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')

lamda_1, lamda_2 = symbols('lamda_1, lamda_2')
n_1 = Symbol('n_1')
n_2 = Symbol('n_2')
n = Symbol('n')

#setting up distributions
N_1 = density(Poisson('N_1', lamda_1))(n_1)
N_2 = density(Poisson('N_2', lamda_2))(n_2)
display(N_1)
display(N_2)

print('setting N_2 in terms of N and N_1')
N_2 = N_2.subs(n_2,n-n_1)

display(N_2)

print("N_1 * N_2")
N = N_1 * N_2

#display(N)

Sum(N,(n_1,0,n))

#summation(N,(n_1,0,n))
```

Everything works fine until I try and run the summation. No errors just doesn't do anything and jupyter says it's running. I've let it run for 10 mins and nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring symbols, include their properties: being positive, integer, nonnegative, etc. This helps SymPy decide whether some transformations are legitimate.

```
lamda_1, lamda_2 = symbols('lamda_1, lamda_2', positive=True)
n_1, n_2, n = symbols('n_1 n_2 n', nonnegative=True, integer=True)
```

Unfortunately, summation still fails because SymPy cannot come up with [the key trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221087): multiplying and dividing by `factorial(n)`. It seems one has to tell it to do that.

```
s = summation(N*factorial(n), (n_1, 0, n))/factorial(n)
print(s.simplify())
```

This prints

```
Piecewise(((lamda_1 + lamda_2)**n*exp(-lamda_1 - lamda_2)/factorial(n), ((-n >= 0) & (lamda_1/lamda_2 <= 1)) | ((-n < 0) & (lamda_1/lamda_2 <= 1))), (lamda_2**n*exp(-lamda_1 - lamda_2)*Sum(lamda_1**n_1*lamda_2**(-n_1)/(factorial(n_1)*factorial(n - n_1)), (n_1, 0, n)), True))
```

which is a piecewise formula full of unnecessary conditions... but if we ignore those conditions (they are just artifacts of how SymPy performed the summation), the correct result

```
((lamda_1 + lamda_2)**n*exp(-lamda_1 - lamda_2)/factorial(n)
```

is there.

Aside: avoid doing `import *` from both sympy and sympy.stats, there are notational clashes such as `E` being 2.718... versus expected value. `from sympy.stats import density, Poisson` would be better. Also, `N` is a built-in SymPy function and is best avoided as a variable name.